# Python - Ask for input and set to sequence and sort

Tags: python, list, sorting

I was assigned to complete a short program and as a beginner, this is harder than what I know. Please help!

1. Get input from user to enter into a sequence of first and last names - with a space between
2. Put the inputted names into a list called 'full_names'
3. Copy list to another 2d list called 'other_list' that has first name and last names in separate columns
4. Sort that 'other_list' ascending order of 1st name
5. Make a new 2d list named 'rank' w/ sorted first and last name and their index in 'full names' list

If someone can even tell me where to begin that would be great!

Comment: Hmmm. Show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Start with [Python's built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Notably, for this problem you'll want to use:

- [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)
- [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)
- [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) / [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)

You've already broken the problem down into steps, you'll probably find all the functions you need on that page. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> Get input from user to enter into a sequence of first and last names -
>   with a space between :

First take input from user in sequence :

Generally we take input as :

```
user_input=input()
```

But in your problem you want to take input in sequences so:

```
user_input=str(input().split())
```

> Put the inputted names into a list called 'full_names'

User_input will store in a list format so instead of using user_input variable name use full_names :

```
full_names=str(input().split())
```

> Copy list to another 2d list called 'other_list' that has first name
>   and last names in separate columns

```
other_list=full_names[:]
```

> Sort that 'other_list' ascending order of 1st name

You can use sorted() in-built function:

```
sorted(other_list)
```

I didn't understand last part what you want there.